# Why my data file cannot change when I click on the button?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, import

I have a app that read all information from my data.json file. I import the file and pass by props to the components.

I'm trying to change the language, changing my data.json import path.

Now I have a `import data from './data/data.json'`, but I want to have two language. 
Then, I translated the data.json and create another two data files `./data/data-en.json` and `./data/data-pt.json`.

And made a button to change between `pt` and `en`.

When I click on the button, nothing works.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';
import AnotherComponent from './AnotherComponent';

import data from './data/data.json';
import english from './data/data-en.json';
import portuguese from './data/data-pt.json';

class MyApp extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isToggleOn: true };
    this.state = { data: english };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState(state => ({
      isToggleOn: !state.isToggleOn
    }));
    if (this.state.isToggleOn) {
      this.setState(state => ({
        data: english
      }))
    } else {
      this.setState(state => ({
        data: portuguese
      }))
    }
    console.log(data)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
          {this.state.isToggleOn ? 'en' : 'pt'}
        </button>
        <MyComponent data={data.mycomponent} />
        <AnotherComponent data={data.anothercomponent} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MyApp;
```

How can I change my data?

Thanks

Comment: Hello Gustavo, be careful because you assign twice to `this.state` in your constructor!

Comment: @Gramatiik yeah, I'm beginning on dev world. Thanks for the advision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem just puting `this.state.` in my components:

```
<MyComponent data={this.state.data.mycomponent} />
<AnotherComponent data={this.state.data.anothercomponent} />
```

Anyway, thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

The `setState` is not synchronous, so in your `handleClick` you should use a callback to have the new state and do your things:

```
handleClick() {
  this.setState(state => ({
    isToggleOn: !state.isToggleOn,
    data: state.isToggleOn ? portuguese : english,
  }));
  console.log(data);
}
```

Also no need to initialize state twice in constructor so

Change

```
this.state = { isToggleOn: true };
this.state = { data: english };
```

To

```
this.state = {
  isToggleOn: true,
  data: english
}
```

Here more information about `setState`: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: I fixed my problem just puting `this.state.` in my components:

Anyway, thanks very much.